# Скрытое открытие браузера и страницы

Tags: wsh

Добрый вечер.
Есть скрипт скрытого открытия браузера:

```
var WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WSHShell.Run("iexplore",0);
```

Вопрос: что добавить в скрипт что бы указать какую именно страницу этот скрипт открывал в этом браузере?

к примеру:

```
Window.Open('http://сайт.ru');
```

не срабатывает!

Answer (score 1):

Всё гениальное просто...

```
WSHShell.Run("iexplore www.hashcode.ru", 0);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! И вправду все гениальное - просто!
Тогда вопрос на засыпку: у открываемой страницы есть звуковой поток! можно ли как то в этом же скрипте отключить звук? и можно ли отключить звук конкретно на эту страницу? заранее благодарен!

И еще Как открыть 2 адреса сразу?
WSHShell.Run("iexplore www.сайт1.ru www.сайт2.ru", 0); 
верно?